# Como calcular correctamente el porcentaje de productividad en Power BI

Tags: powerbi

En PowerBI estoy realizando el cálculo del porcentaje de la productividad de cada uno de los técnicos que atienden tickets, para calcular la productividad de cada uno estoy usando la formula "*tickets attended* **100 / total tickets*", para calcular la productividad estoy creando una medida nueva en donde estoy ejecutando la siguiente formula:

```
Measure = DIVIDE(Tickets[Tickets Attended]*100,Tickets[Total Tickets])
```

Los "Tickets Attended" los estoy obteniendo en base a una medida la cual su fórmula es la siguiente:

```
Tickets Attended = CALCULATE(COUNTAX(Tickets,Tickets[Status]),Tickets[Status]="Resolved" || Tickets[Status]="Cancelled")
```

Lo único que me interesa tener en los "Tickets Atendidos" son los que se encuentran en Estado Resuelta o Cancelado.

Para calcular "Total Tickets" estoy utilizando la siguiente formula en una medida, en donde utilizo la medida anterior de "Tickets Atendidos"

```
Total Tickets = SUMX(VALUES(Tickets[ID Ticket]),Tickets[Tickets Attended])
```

Para dar un ejemplo más claro de lo que quiero realizar en Power Bi, lo he realizado en Excel de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Explico la fórmula para realizar el cálculo de la productividad de cada Técnico, para el User1 es:

```
41*100/197 = 20.8121
```

El error que estoy presentando al agregar esta medida a la tabla en Power BI es que todos los valores en la productividad de cada técnico me da como resultado 100.

Cuál sería la formula correcta que deba usar? Agradezco quien me pueda orientar en como realizar la formula correcta.